# Rodar texto e substituir primeiro link

Tags: php, string

Tenho uma variável nomeada `$text` onde nela é armazenado textos que o usuário escreve.

> `$text = "Hahahha que legal esse site, consegui responder todas minhas
>   perguntas lá https://pt.stackoverflow.com/"

`

O que eu preciso?

Eu tenho uma função nomeada makelink($url); que monta uma prévia do conteúdo do link. Ou seja, eu preciso criar uma função que vá pegar o **PRIMEIRO** link do texto e joga-lo nessa função, a função vai criar uma prévia do link e ira retornar um output com o resultado em HTML, depois de jogar o link na função eu preciso que esse o output disso vá para o final do texto.

Ou seja:

> `$textfinal = "Hahahha que legal esse site, consegui responder todas
>   minhas perguntas lá https://pt.stackoverflow.com/" 
>   *PREVIA DO LINK*`

Vejo como uma boa alternativa fazer um filtro com regex ou algo do tipo (não é minha área) para poder capturar todo tipo de link..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tenta da seguinte forma:

```
$string =  SUA_STRING;
preg_match_all('https?://(([^ .]+)\.)+[^ .]{2,4}(/[^ /]+)', $string, $conteudo);

$link = $conteudo[0][0];//link
```

Answer (score 1):

Meu caro, você vai precisar utilizar uma expressão regular para pegar todo valor que tiver como início http ou https. Seria algo mais menos nessa idéia:

```
https?://(([^ .]+)\.)+[^ .]{2,4}(/[^ /]+)*
```

Comment: Sim, e como executar a funcao em sí?

Answer (score 1):

Utilize o seguinte código:

```
$links = array();
$text = "Hahahha que legal esse site, consegui responder todas minhas perguntas lá http://pt.stackoverflow.com/"
$regexp = "[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~\#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~\#?&//=]*)?";
if(preg_match_all("#$regexp#", $text, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
    foreach($matches as $match) {
        $links[] = $match[0];
    }
}

print_r($links);
```